# 'find_element_by_xpath' not working correctly Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to make a bot that comment on a certain pin on pinterest, the pin has two tabs, photos and comments, I am trying to click on comments so that I can post my comment, I used xpath of that element, but when I ran it, it clicked on a picture below the comment button, I ensured that the xpath is unique, I tried to find it in the console, and it gave me one result which is what I wanted, so I don't understand what is wrong, can someone help me?

pin URL: [URL](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/384283780713508363/)

```
try:
   WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
          EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'comments')]")))
except TimeoutException:
   pass
else:
   sleep(3)
   self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "comments"]').click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZocz.png)

Comment: Please check .. it is inside the iframe?

Comment: I will try to  .

Comment: I checked, I believe it is not inside an iframe

Comment: What is the error, you are getting. If it is no such element Exception. You need to add wait

Comment: No, It just clicks on the wrong element

Comment: it clicks on a photo beneath the comment button

Comment: you can go to the pin URL that I gave in the question for more details

Comment: Please attach the element screenshot. press F12 -> search the element -> add screenshot

Comment: @JayanthBala just updated and added the pic you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please following xpath in your code, and also when i open the URL in my browser, located comment box is not visible, better you need to scroll down and then do the comment.

Xpath to post comment is

> //textarea[@data-test-id='communityItemTextBox']

Xpath to get total comments

> //h3[contains(text(),'comments')]

I am seeing only one comment box in that site
[image]

and if you logged in,

please add wait time in your code before entering value

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@data-test-id='communityItemTextBox']"))
```

Comment: there is that type of a pin that contains 2  tabs, one for photo and one for comments, so I want to click on comments to view that textarea

Comment: but i am seeing only one text area.

Comment: if you go to the url I gave in the question and the image you will understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: you want to post a comment, i see only one comment box by default. and i have mentioned the right xpath here. when i try to comment, i am able to comment. what else is the problem ? any error you are getting in the console ?

Comment: Have you logged in ? because in your pic, there is no arrow mark to minimize/maximize the comment section.

Comment: isn't there a tab called comments that you must tab to enter the comments section??
I want to know how to click, I tried to click it but it clicks on a photo beneath the tab

Comment: may be because you have a different resolution, I don't know

Comment: can we have quick chat over google hangout, it is hard to share screenshot here. jayanthbala1993@gmail.com

Comment: have you tried this xpath ?

//textarea[@data-test-id='communityItemTextBox']

Comment: yes I did try your answer

Comment: I believe it is something in pinterest that is preventing me from clicking in the right position

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the `"]"` square bracket

Comment: I think it would have told me if there was an error like this

Comment: I editted the code on stackoverflow so I might have forgot it

Comment: Under that "div" there should be an anchor tag that has the link, click that anchor tag, for there is no use clicking a "div" tag.

Comment: do you have any idea how to achieve what I want, like a work around

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-test-id='canonicalCommentsTab']").click()
```

Comment: it didn't work, same result